# How to convert dataframe column of str to float numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have column of str values which I want to convert to float numpy array, is there any built in function to do this? If not, How do I do this?

Dataframe looks as follows:
[image]

Feature column has all values as str:

```
'[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 2.40159345 0. ],' 
'[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 8.59722424 0. ]', 
'[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]', 
'[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]', 
'[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1.38265193 0. ]', 
'[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]',
```

I want it to become of type numpy array - numpy.ndarray of floats:

````
[0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         8.59722424 0.        ],
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]', '[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.],
[0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         1.38265193 0.        ],
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.],```
````

Comment: How do you end up with this in the first place?

Comment: I am working on a project which requires me to identify if 2 people are kin or not. What I have done is extracted features from images using VGG 16, the 1st column is exactly that. After extraction, the features were stored in CSV file. Now while trying to read the csv file, the arrays turned into str. This method was suggested by my mentor. Now, I need these features as arrays again to feed to ML classifier. Since SVM isn't reading str (very aptly), and I need to use the csv file instead of storing the features in a variable to use later in the code, I posted the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK you'll have to do it manually:

```py
rows = []
for row in df["Feature"]:
    rows.append([float(x) for x in row.strip("[]").split(" ")])
arr = np.Array(rows)
```

Comment: Perhaps they had merely noticed that I had forgotten to remove the brackets.  Updated.  Or perhaps the question is really asking something very different...

Answer (score -1):

You can use astype() function.

Convert dataframe as :

```
df = df.astype('int32')
```

[Check this documentation of pandas.DataFrame.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Comment: I don't think this will work in this particular instance, since the first column contains (I think) numbers separated by spaces